# CSS style on an element only of a table with a specific class

Tags: css, html-table, css-selectors

I was never any good with CSS, and it's after midnight here, so apologies if this question is too basic.

My table looks like this:

[image]

using this CSS:

```
.zebra_stripe_table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

tbody.zebra_stripe_table 
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
} 

tr.zebra_stripe_table th.zebra_stripe_table td.zebra_stripe_table {
  text-align: center;
  /* padding: 16px; */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.zebra_stripe_table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

I would prefer to have vertical columns on the table, like this:

[image]

which I achieved with

```
.zebra_stripe_table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

  .zebra_stripe_table tbody
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid ddd;
}

.zebra_stripe_table tr, th, td {
  text-align: center;
  /* padding: 16px; */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.zebra_stripe_table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

The difference being changing

```
tr.zebra_stripe_table th.zebra_stripe_table td.zebra_stripe_table
```

to

```
.zebra_stripe_table tr, th, td
```

but, that adds cell border to the only other table in the AngularJS project (which does not have the class "zebra_stripe_table").

So, I imagine that the first syntax is correct, applying a style to tr, th & td only of the class `zebra_stripe_table`.

Question, how do I get those vertical stripes with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the center alignment inside the cells change this selector

```
.zebra_stripe_table tr, th, td { ... }
```

to this:

```
.zebra_stripe_table th, .zebra_stripe_table td {... }
```

(You don't need to include the `tr` here, but you need to have `.zebra_stripe_table` as a parent for * both*  `th` and `td`)

About the alternating background color for the rows, change your last CSS rule from

```
.zebra_stripe_table tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #f2f2f2; }
```

to

```
.zebra_stripe_table tr:nth-child(even) td { background-color: #f2f2f2; }
```

(It's the *cells* which get the background, not the rows)